# Не поддерживается на вашем устройстве

Tags: android, google-play

Есть простое приложение. В окне запускаю через библиотеку XWalkView сайт и всё.

Всё работает на многих устройствах.

Минимальная версия SDK 16.

Сделал APK и залил в Google Play в альфа-тестирование.

Скинул ссылку знакомому у которого версия Android 5.0.2 и ему Play Market пишет следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так написали с соответствующей проблемой вот на этом устройстве:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Информация с google play:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот собственно Build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hodite.shcherbuk"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2'
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:20.50.533.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Наверное у знакомого аппарат на процессоре 64 Bit и Вы не подключили соответствующую библиотеку от Crosswalk. Попробуйте добавить `compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:20.50.533.12-arm64'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно проблема была в manifest.

У меня было прописано разрешение на GYROSCOPE.

Из-за этого разрешения было заблочено более 10000 устройств.
Удалил разрешение и всё работает)